# How to retrieve the last document in a firebase collection. I would also like to get the document fields value

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How to retrieve the last document from a Cloud Firestore collection? I would also like to get the document fields value.

Here this the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

> How to retrieve the last document in a firebase collection?

To solve this, you need to use a query that should look like this:

```
FirebaseFirestore rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
Query query = rootRef.collection("High Volume")
    .orderBy("Time", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
    .limit(1);
query.get().addOnCompleteListener(/* ... */);
```

This query will order the results according to the `time` property and will limit the results to one.

Comment: In terms of performance, would sorting be better than having a flag property "isLast" for each item? So that we would make a query where isLast == true to find the last one. Indeed the drawback is having to keep such a flag up to date all the time.

Comment: @Francesco I don't think it's a better approach since for every new addition of a document you need to update the old isLast document.

Comment: Totally agree on that. In general I was wondering whether sorting the dataset to get the latest entry was (much) more expensive than a query over a boolean property and whether there could be other possibilities then.

Comment: @Francesco The performance comes from the number of elements that are returned by your query. If you query the database and use a `limit(1)` call is the exact same thing if you query the database over a boolean property that returns a single ement.

Comment: how to transform this QuerySnapshot into a DocumentSnapshot after querying?

Comment: @Nuqo You cannot. There is no inheritance relationship between them. What are you looking for?

Comment: @Alex Mamo I couldn't find a way to save the document as a model-class/access the data of the document like when I use 'documentSnapshot.data()' of a  'DocumentSnapshot', but i figured it out now, thanks!

I added '.get().then((value) => value.docs[0])' to your provided solution