# Add timestamp insteard auto-geenrated key in firebase document

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to be able to query the latest document from the firebase, and I fount that I have to refer to the timestemp.

However in my database I do have auto-generated id's

[image]

I did came across this question [How to retrieve the last document in a firebase collection. I would also like to get the document fields value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362292/how-to-retrieve-the-last-document-in-a-firebase-collection-i-would-also-like-to) and discovered that you can have time stem instead of the keys.

I adding and updating the data to firebase like that:

```
 firebase.firestore().collection(collectionName).add({
        data: data,
        updated: getDate()
      });

firebase.firestore().collection(collectionName).doc().update({
        data: data,
        updated: getDate()
      });
```

So I wonder how would you achieve using the date as a keys
 [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to a specific string to be the ID of the document, then you can't use `add()`, and also can't use `doc()` with no parameters.  You will need to build the string yourself, and pass it to `doc()`.

Personally, I don't recommend this.  I suggest accepting the random ID, and instead use a server timestamp as a field in the document.  You can use that to sort the results of a query, and limit the result set to 1 in order to get the newest document.

Comment: I do have an `update` timestamp field in my document, so you think I just have to use that then?

Comment: Sure, if that meets the need of your query.