# Reference last document in a Firestore Collection

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I recently learned that we can actually set FieldValue to reference a document. But what I really was curious about was if it was also possible to reference the last document of a Collection.

Say for example I have a Data Structure which looks like this:

```
Chat
    CHAT_ID
        last : (Reference To the Last Document in the "Messages" Collection)

Messages
    MSG_ID_001
       msg : Some Message
    MSG_ID_002
       msg : Some Message
    MSG_ID_003
       msg : Some Message
```

So now I want set the reference such that it always refers to the last document in the Messages Collection (In this case MSG_ID_003).

So is it possible??

Comment: I was looking into your question and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52362292/how-to-retrieve-the-last-document-in-a-firebase-collection-i-would-also-like-to) post, you should be able to do something similar if you have some way to sort your data, please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I know that i can query the database that way. But instead of updating it from the user side i want the reference to automatically take the last document's reference. I want to do this without creating a firebase function. @LluisMuñoz

Answer (score 0):

Having a field referencing the last field of a collection, and automatically updating that reference so it always points to the last field, is not possible in Firestore.

I would recommend just making a query to get the last document reference whenever you need it. But if you want to do it, as a workaround, you can update the field yourself, and there are a couple of ways to do it:

- Updating it from your code every time you add a new field to the collection you want to reference with an update query.
- Creating a Cloud Function using the `onCreate` or `onWrite` triggers to update the reference field each time changes are made to the collection. Please note that this approach, although the most reliable, can be pretty expensive if you have to update that field frequently.

You  can take a look at [this](https://youtu.be/Elg2zDVIcLo?t=275) video that explains what reference fields are used for in Firestore.